# Is it faster to enumerate through subviews or an NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, arrays, optimization

I am really trying to optimize my code for moving `UIImageViews`.

I have a primary method for enumerating through all of my `UIImageViews`.

Which enumeration would perform faster, or would they both perform exactly the same?

Example 1: In this example I enumerate through all `UIImageViews` in my `UIViewController`'s view

```
 for (UIImageView *imageView in self.view.subviews)
{
    ...
}
```

Example 2: In this example I enumerate through all `UIImageViews` in my `NSMutableArray`. The array always contains all of the `UIImageViews` found in `self.view.subviews` (It's just a copy of all the UIImageViews normally found in self.view.subviews that I only need to create once)

```
 for (UIImageView *imageView in self.imageViews)
{
    ...
}
```

So which example should provide me with a faster and more optimized enumeration? Note that these are constantly enumerated by a CADisplayLink that I have setup. Also note that `self.view.subviews` returns an `NSArray` so perhaps this `NSArray` is constantly being created when I use the first enumeration, making me think that the `NSMutableArray` approach would perform better and have less overhead but i'm not sure.

Edit: All of the subviews are `UIImageViews`. I am also not sure if there is any significant overhead when using the subviews property because it looks like it may do some "behind-the-scenes" work to get me that NSArray.

Comment: Are all the subviews uiimageview?

Comment: Yes, assume all of the subviews are UIImageViews.

Comment: I prefer the first one to save more code:)

Comment: Are you trying to solve a performance problem? Did you measure significant overhead? If not, stop now and read up on premature optimization.

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency, I'm surprised you're having them "constantly enumerated by a `CADisplayLink`". I would have thought that the impact of that would be far greater than `NSMutableArray` v `subviews` impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the subviews, you can use the `Tag` property to do it very fast

Example:

Add a tag to `UIimageView` through `code or xib`

```
myImageView.tag = 1;
```

Then,

```
 UIImageView *myImageView = ([[self.view viewWithTag:1] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])?(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1]:nil;
```

**About your iteration codes**

Assume all of the subviews are UIImageViews then the first code  will be the most efficient.

```
for (UIImageView *imageView in self.view.subviews)
```

Comment: I don't know how I wound up downvoting this.  Allow me to remedy that.  +1

Comment: After doing some benchmarking, it appears that there is no significant difference in performance between the two examples. I ended up going with the subviews enumeration because I don't need to worry about constantly keeping the NSMutableArray updated. I also looked at the documentation for the subviews property and it looks to be safe to enumerate because it is just a copy. As for the CADisplayLink, I use it to constantly integrate the motion (and a few other mechanics) of my UIImageViews.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with a simple view with a couple of imageviews on it, it probably doesn't matter too much, and the performance issues are negligible. Benchmark the two approaches in Instruments, and I'd be shocked if there is an observable difference. And as I alluded to above, your use of a `CADisplayLink` can have far greater performance repercussions than a `NSMutableArray` ever will.

Conceptually, though, as your app grows in complexity, there are huge benefits in following the [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) pattern. In this world, there is a huge difference between the model (which might be backed by something as simple as your mutable array or as complicated as some persistent store or some network service) and the view (which, once you optimize it), may only represent a very small subset of the the whole model, employing lazy loading or dequeueing and reusing cells/views.

A wonderful example is a photo gallery app where you have lots of photo albums and each album has lots of photos. It would be crazy to try to load all of those images into image views if, for example, many of those image views are not visible at any given time, much less even load have separate image views for all of those images. So your model might be some object structure that captures the full set of albums and references to the photos, but your view might only have a few image views on it (e.g. the "current" image, the "next" image, and the "previous" image).

In a scenario like this, you'd be asking for a world of trouble if you start trying to load all of the images into image views and adding all of those image views as subviews. And even if you do, as you get more sophisticated, you may find yourself loading the imageviews with renditions of images that are down-sampled to a resolution appropriate for your device or what have you.

So, in short, looking at your simple example, I think there is a negligible performance hit in creating your `NSMutableArray`, but it leads you down the road of correctly thinking about the differences between your model (the data backing your app) and the view (the stuff you do to present and optimize your user interface). It probably doesn't matter for tiny little apps, but as your app gets more sophisticated (lots of images, user interface where you have some images that are not visible (scrolled off the screen), then this distinction becomes far more important.

We don't know enough about your app to be able to say where you fall on that spectrum of complexity. Sounds like it's simple enough that it might not matter, but I think it's good to adopt MVC thought processes sooner rather than later.

#### References

- [Model View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) in *Core Competencies.*
- [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14) in the *Concepts in Objective-C Programming.*